# Retirar sequencia númerica de string

Tags: php, regex

Estou com o seguinte problema, acredito que consiga resolve-lo com expressões regulares, mas sou pessimo com o mesmo.

Digamos que eu tenha uma string desse jeito: `CONECTOR BNC FEMEA + F MACHO 024267` ou assim `PLUG P-4 UNIVERSAL 006-096`, a posição dos números podem estar em qualquer lugar, começo, meio ou fim, preciso tirar as sequências númericas que sejam iguais ou maiores que 3 digitos.

Esses digitos geralmente são como referência e estou usando essas informações para buscar imagens usando a API do Google Custom Search, se eles forem passados para realizar a busca geralmente não retorna nenhum resultado.

Resultado desejado:
Entrada: `CONECTOR BNC FEMEA + F MACHO 024267`
Saída: `CONECTOR BNC FEMEA + F MACHO`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para capturar/substituir três ou mais digitos seguidos use a regex `\d{3,}`. `\d` significa números (0-9), as chaves funcionam como quantificador no caso obrigam três digitos ou mais a serem capturados.

```
$str = 'CONECTOR BNC FEMEA + F MACHO 024267 23';
$nova = preg_replace('/\d{3,}/', '', $str);
echo $nova;
```

Resultado:

```
CONECTOR BNC FEMEA + F MACHO 23
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado. :)